# Transformation of a number to different number using recursion

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I am trying to make an algorithm for the following task:

- I have two integers a ≤ b
- The algorithm has to transform *a* into *b* by adding 1 and multiply by 2 operations. For example, if *a* = 5 and *b* = 23 the program should output something like 23 = ((5 * 2 + 1) * 2 + 1)
- I have to use recursion

I've already Googled many times but all I could find is ideas on how to transform a matrix, how to do geometric transformations, how to transform string into another string and similar stuff.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Does it always have to be *2+1, or can it be any of the two? How do you transform 3 to 9?

Comment: Ignore the multiplication by 2 and simply add 1 to a until you get b.

Comment: @Hyperboreus - No, it can be any of the two. 9 = (3+1)*2 +1 or 9 = 3*2 + 1 + 1 + 1. I guess whenever _a_ is odd there will be + 1 and the end.

Comment: Pls understand that `a*2+1`, `(a+1)*2` and `a*2+1+1+1` are 3 different expressions :)

Comment: So, do you want to find the combination of *2 and +1 which transforms the input to the output in the LEAST numbers of steps? Because the trivial way of only using +1 all the time (as user207442) said will always work.

Comment: @Nath based on your comments I edited my answer, pls see below.

Comment: @Hyperboreus - Yes, I should have said that earlier. I overlooked the problem - it says "... by a minimum sequence of +1 and *2 operations."

Comment: @Nath I posted you a way to find the minimum number of operations.

Comment: Thank you very much to everyone for the quick responses. I didn't expect that :)

Comment: I am new to the community here and it takes me a while to get used to the way it works ( I mean the comments section and the answers ).

Comment: I need to study your solutions, guys. I want to understand how exactly you solved the problem. Not to just copy/paste the solution. Great community is here :) Thanks again to everyone for the help.

Comment: Just being curious - why when adding new comments to my question the latter doesn't go up in the list with the questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the way to find the transformation with the **minimum number** of operations:

(EDIT: Added parenthesis)

```
public static void main (String [] args)
{
    int a = 5, b = 23;
    System.out.println (transform (a, b) + " = " + b);
}

public static String transform (int a, int b)
{
    if (a == b) return "" + a;
    if (b % 2 == 0 && 2 * a <= b)
    {
        b = b / 2;
        return transform (a, b) + " * 2";
    }
    else
    {
        b = b - 1;
        return "(" + transform (a, b) + " + 1)";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Hyperboreus. I'll need to study your solution. Just out of curiosity - are you using Aslan986's suggestion with the mentioned algorithm? I am asking because it took me two days to find some solution of the problem and came up with nothing, while you guys were so quick with ideas / solutions.

Comment: No what Aslan referred to is an algotithm that operates over elliptic curves. Nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: When I run your code with _transform(5, 23)_ the output that I get is: 5 * 2 + 1 * 2 + 1

Comment: Yes, as I told you, you must still add the parenthesis around the additions: (5 * 2 + 1) * 2 + 1 = 23

Comment: @Nath I added the parenthesis myself.

Comment: OK, I was wondering where exactly in the code I need to include the line that adds parenthesis :)

Comment: @Nath I changed the parenthesis again. Please look at the updated code.

Comment: @Hyperboreus - I had to take pen and paper in order to see what exactly was going on. It's interesting approach by the way - working with _b_ instead of _a_ :)

Comment: @Hyperboreus I would like to understand how the other members's approaches work as well. Especially @anubhava and @Bala R. I am working on different problems all involving recursion. I've found the recursion little tricky and am hoping to get the different points of view in order to understand it in depth. Thank you very much for your prompt responses and solution, Hyperboreus.

Comment: @Hyperboreus How did you find out the right approach for the minimum number of operations?

Comment: @Nath. To be honest: I don't know. I am quite sure that this algorithm yields the minimum step, but I could not prove it formally. Even back at university mathematical proves were one of my Achilles' heels. My hypothesis is that a division by two always brings you at least as far as if not farer than the substraction of one. Based on that, finding the approach for implementing it was easypeasy. The more experience in programming you get, the easier a lot of things look. BTW I understand that you NEED to use recursion here, but for this problem it is not the best approach.

Comment: @Hyperboreus Thanks for the reply. That's fine. I was just curious. You are absolutely right about the experience. Yes, I had to use recursion. BTW I hope @anubhava and @Bala R would reply. I want to understand why their approaches don't work.

Comment: @Hyperboreus I like your algorithm. It's neat modifying _b_ until it reaches _a_ versus the opposite.

Answer (score 2):

Following method should work for you I think:

```
int transform(int a, int b) {
   if (a>= b)
      return a;
   else if (a*2 <= b)
      return transform(2*a, b);
   else
      return transform(a + 1, b);
}
```

Comment: What if, say, a=2 and b=3?  transform(2, 3) gives 5 - so you overshoot b.

Comment: You re right but question asked for using this formula earlier however based on OP's recent comments I think I need to alter my answer. Pls see my edited answer.

Comment: Obviously there is something that I don't understand but when I use your code and have line _System.out.println(transform(5, 23));_ the output that I get is _23_ ?

Answer (score 2):

This actually prints it, but it may not be exactly what you are looking for I'm not sure.

```
private static String doDo(int a, int b, StringBuilder sb) {
    if (a == b) {
      String ret = sb.toString();
      int charCount = ret.replaceAll("[^)]", "").length();
      for (int i = 0; i < charCount; i++)
        ret = "(" + ret;
      return ret;
    }
    if (a < (b/2f)) {
      sb.append(")*2+1");
      return doDo(a*2 + 1, b, sb);
    } else {
      sb.append("+1");
      return doDo(a+1, b, sb);
    }
  }

System.out.println(doDo(5, 23, new StringBuilder().append("5")));
```

This is printed -> `((5)*2+1)*2+1`

Answer (score 1):

here's some pseudo code that you can use

```
transform(a, b)
start
   if a >= b
       return
   else
     print formatted progress 
     transform(a * 2 + 1, b)
end
```

Comment: With every level going deeper _a_ is increasing by *2 + 1 until it gets to _a >= b_. But I don't understand how I can use this in order to get the transformation. It's kind of similar thing that I don't understand in @anubhava's approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to over shoot then use this (modified version of @anubhava's solution).

```
int transform(int a, int b) {
   if (a >= b){
      return a;
   } else {
      int c = a*2 + 1;
      if (c>b){
          return a;
      } else {
          return transform(c, b);
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version that uses recursion to determine the optimal strategy for doing the transform in the minimal number of operations.  I assume that each time you double, that counts as one operation; each time you add 1, that counts as one operation, and the goal is to minimise the total number of operations.

And testing it on the 5->23 example yields:

```
((((5)*2)+1)*2)+1=23
```

You could be terser with the syntax, but hopefully a little verbosity helps to show the intent of the code.

Hat tip to josh.trow as I used his idea on how to do the string formatting.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DoubleAndAddAlgorithm {
    public enum Op {
        DOUBLE, ADD_ONE
    }

    private static List<Op> getOptimalTransform(int a, int b) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        // Returns the list of operations that comprises the optimal way to get from a to b

        // If a is already bigger than b, we have a problem
        if (a > b) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("a cannot be greater than b");
        }

        List<Op> result = new ArrayList<Op>();

        // If we can get there in one operation, do so
        if (2*a == b) {
            result.add(Op.DOUBLE);
        } else if (a+1 == b) {
            result.add(Op.ADD_ONE);
        }

        // If doubling would cause us to overshoot, all we can do is add 1
        // and take it from there...
        else if (2*a > b) {
            result.add(Op.ADD_ONE);
            result.addAll(getOptimalTransform(a+1, b));
        }

        // Otherwise, let's try doubling, and let's try adding one, and use
        // recursion to see which gets us to the target quicker
        else {
            List<Op> trialResultDouble = getOptimalTransform(2*a, b);
            List<Op> trialResultAddOne = getOptimalTransform(a+1, b);

            // Let's say (arbitrarily), that if neither operation results in us
            // getting to the target any quicker than the other, we choose to add 1
            if (trialResultDouble.size() < trialResultAddOne.size()) {
                result.add(Op.DOUBLE);
                result.addAll(trialResultDouble);
            } else {
                result.add(Op.ADD_ONE);
                result.addAll(trialResultAddOne);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static String getFormattedResult(int a, int b) {
        try {
            List<Op> ops = getOptimalTransform(a, b);

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(Integer.toString(a));

            for (Op op: ops) {
                if (op == Op.DOUBLE) {
                    sb.insert(0, "(");
                    sb.append(")*2");
                } else if (op == Op.ADD_ONE) {
                    sb.insert(0, "(");
                    sb.append(")+1");
                }
            }

            sb.append("=");
            sb.append(Integer.toString(b));

            return sb.toString();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            return "Illegal arguments supplied";
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println( getFormattedResult(5, 23) );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Search for an algorithm called double&add, it's the dual of the square&multiply one...i'm sorry but i don't know the details.

Comment: Thank you, Aslan986. I am just checking it out.